# how to add a new bin to a record in aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I have an existing record with two bins I need to add a third bin to it using the java client API

```
val client = new AerospikeClient("localhost",3000)
val bin1 = new Bin("name", "John")
val bin2 = new Bin("age" , 33)
client.add(null, key,bin1,bin2)
```

now how do I add a third bin ?

```
val bin3 = new Bin("phone" , "555555123123")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same key and then just insert the  new bin. This will update the existing record with the new bin. The way you are proceeding about it is correct.

Comment: client.add(null, key,bin3)

Comment: It's schema-free. Each record can have a different collection of bins, and they're added on the server when the client adds a new one via any of the write operations (put, increment, etc)

Answer (score 1):

As per Aerospike [documentation](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/single.html), behaviour of update and replace is mentioned below:

**update** :    If the record exists, then add or update the specified bins. Bins that are not specified, will remain intact.

**replace** :   If the record exists, then write the specified bins, replacing all prexisting bins.

Therefore, if you just specify the third bin, it will work. It will also work if you specify all three bins and make update or replace call.